# How to add global javascript library

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I started developing a theme for Magento 2.2.0 and now I have to use some external javascript libraries both in my theme and my modules.

So what is the best solution to prevent loading the same library twice?

Should I create a new Module containing my javascript libraries and refernce them in my other modules?

**EDIT:**

For example I have a Module which requires a specific library like swiper.js.
So I would require it somehow with `My_Module/path/to/swiper.js`.
But if I have another Module with the same dependency `My_Module2/path/to/swiper.js` it now is loaded twice?

In Magento2 I can require `jquery` and any other core library from anywhere but the documentation says you shouldnt put js into mageroot/lib/web/js.

Comment: Can you explain more about the issue `So what is the best solution to prevent loading the same library twice?`?

Answer (score 0):

You should not have to worry about that. Magento 2 and Require JS are made so that they merge the individual require files and create one large file before the includes are taking place.

More info here: http://inchoo.net/magento-2/javascript-bundling-magento-2/

Comment: Ive read that glob post, but what happens if for example you have `Vendor_Module1/js/my-lib.js` and `Vendor_Module2/js/my-lib.js`?
Isnt it then still included twice?